# what is the name of the font name used in iOS as system font

Tags: ios, fonts, uilabel, uifont

I was trying to set the font of UILabel manually. Previously, I use system font black of size 48.
so label.font = UIFont(name: "", size: CGFLoat(48))

what is the name it should be, to make the text of the label has the same look as system black 48.

Comment: ^ Actually it depends on the version of iOS.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(48)
```

Note that if this is not the right weight, you can instead (starting in iOS 8.2) call `systemFontOfSize:weight:`.